# SQLite : multiple inserts in a single query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two sqlite tables:

**user**:

```
ID  city
--  ----
1   ankara
2   istanbul
3   ankara
```

**action**

```
userID  isFree
------  ------
```

and a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO action (userID, isFree) 
VALUES ( (SELECT ID FROM user WHERE city = 'ankara'), true);
```

This query inserts just the first user to the action table, but I want to insert first and third users into the action table.

Are there any way to do this in a single query?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO action(userID, isFree) 
 Select ID, true from user where city='ankara';
```